# C# SerialPort DataReceived Event

Tags: c#

I am listening to a serial port for 5 bytes of information. The 5 bytes are needed for full answer to poll. My code listens to serialport data_received event and checks bytesToRead. At times, the event will fire and the bytesToRead is 0. Isn't event to fire only when data is available?

```
public SerialPort wheel = new SerialPort();
public void wheel_DataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (wheel.BytesToRead < 5)
    {
        wheelRetry += 1;
        Log("Wheel Data Received: " + wheel.BytesToRead.ToString() + 
            " bytes. Need 5 bytes. Attempt #: " + wheelRetry.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: First of all, you do not check the *SerialData* event type (passed as part of `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs`. (Hint: Change your event handler to match the delegate type `System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` to make handling of the event args easier without requiring casting.) Check if you get a `SerialData.Chars` or an `SerialData.Eof` event type...

Comment: Perhaps you are also affected by an issue regarding the last byte being 0x13 while using XonXoff handshake. Check [here at MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551590/serial-port-bytestoread-error#) whether this situation applies to you. If so, you will there also find a workaround...

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `ReceivedBytesThreshold` property:

```
var port = new SerialPort();
port.Open();    

//Only raise the event if 5 bytes have been received
port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 5;

port.DataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
    //Handle the data
};
```

Please note that you should hook up the event handler after you have opened the port,
this to prevent a known issue on some platforms which prevents the event from being
raised if it was hooked up before the port was opened.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference source for SerialPort.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialPort.cs), yes, the `DataReceived` event can fire when `BytesToRead` is 0, ***if*** the internal stream's `DataRecieved` event fired and the event args has an `EventType == SerialData.Eof`.  If such is the case then the size of `BytesToRead` isn't taken into account.

Relevant snippet from [CatchReceivedEvents](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialPort.cs#1424), the internal stream's `DataReceived` event handler:

```
bool raiseEvent = false;
try {
    raiseEvent = stream.IsOpen && (SerialData.Eof == e.EventType || BytesToRead >= receivedBytesThreshold);    
}
catch {
    // Ignore and continue. SerialPort might have been closed already! 
}
finally {
    if (raiseEvent)
        eventHandler(this, e);  // here, do your reading, etc. 
}
```

You could modify your event handler, as @elgonzo suggested, so that you can check the `EventType`:

```
public void wheel_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.EventType == SerialData.Eof) //return? possibly nothing to read
...
```